# Domain issues regarding the Duhamel formula for the linear Schrödinger equation

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, schrodinger-operators

I have some questions in succession regarding the rigorous domain issues about a Duhamel expansion formula (stated near the end of my post) for the linear Schrödinger equation.

Consider a linear Schrödinger equation (in the form of an evolution equation) $$i\frac{d}{dt}\psi(t) = (-\Delta +V)\psi(t).$$ Here $V$ is a time-independent  multiplier operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Assume that $(-\Delta +V)$ is self-adjoint and that $\psi(0)$ is in $D (-\Delta +V) \subset L^2(\mathbb{R}^d) $. These assumptions ensure the existence and uniqueness of a solution $\psi(t)$ which is in $D (-\Delta +V) $ for all $t$.  My **first question** is whether $D (-\Delta +V)$ is always contained in $D(\Delta)\cap D(V)$. (In my limited knowledge I only know situations where one can show that $-\Delta +V$ is essentially self-adjoint on a subset of  $D(\Delta)\cap D(V)$, but how big could the domain of the self-adjoint extension be?)

If the answer to the above question is yes, then it is okay to write
$$i\frac{d}{dt}\psi(t) = -\Delta \psi(t) +V \psi(t).$$
Then applying the Duhamel formula,
$$\psi(t) = e^{it\Delta}\psi(0)+\int_{0}^te^{i(t-s)\Delta}(-iV)\psi(s)ds.$$
If we note that the term $\psi(s)$ in the right-hand side is just the left-hand side with a different argument, we then have that
$$ \psi(t) = e^{it\Delta}\psi(0)+\int_{0}^te^{i(t-s)\Delta} (-iV)\Big(e^{is\Delta}\psi(0)+\int_{0}^s e^{i(s-r)\Delta} (-iV)\psi(r)dr\Big)ds.\tag{1} $$
My **second question** is whether it is valid to expand the parenthesis in the right-hand side of $(1)$—basically, whether $e^{is\Delta}\psi(0)\in D(V)$ for all $s$. I am asking this because I have seen a few times the following formula whose derivation would require one to expand the parenthesis in the RHS of $(1)$ and repeat the process. Said formula is
$$\psi(t) = \sum_ {n=0} ^n \psi_n (t)+\text{remainder}$$ where
$$\psi_n(t) = \int_0^t\cdots\int_0^t ds_0 ds_1 \cdots ds_n\delta(t-\sum_{j=0}^n s_j) e^{is_0\Delta} (-iV) e^{is_1\Delta}(-iV)\cdots(-iV) e^{is_n\Delta}\psi(0). $$

This is a useful formula. When $V$ is in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ everything is fine, but in general, wouldn’t one have to worry about whether $\psi(0)\in D( e^{is_0\Delta} V e^{is_1\Delta}V\cdots V e^{is_n\Delta})$? My **third question** is whether there is a “nice” space of functions $X$ that is contained in $D( e^{is_0\Delta} V e^{is_1\Delta}V\cdots V e^{is_n\Delta})$? Would $X=D(-\Delta+ V)$ work? Would $X = C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ work?